# Cleaning up Socket.io session data with timers

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, timer

I was thinking about extending the functionality of node.js server running Socket.io which I am currently using to allow a client (iOS app) to communicate with a server, so that it could have persistent session data between connection.

On initial connection the server passes the client a session id which the client will store and pass to the server later on if it reconnects after disconnecting, this would allow the client to resume its session without having to re-provide the server with certain information about its current state (obviously when it comes to actual implementation it will be more secure than this).

I want to make it so that the session eventually expires, so it has a max lifetime or if it hasn't been continued after a certain time it times-out. To do this I was thinking of using timers for each session. Im not actually sure how node.js or javascript timers (setTimeout) work in the background and am concerned that having 1000s of session timers could lead to a lot of memory/cpu usage. Could this be a potential issue, should I have a garbage collector that cycles every minute or so and deletes expired session data? What is the kind of most optimal way in terms of least impact on performance method I can do to accomplish this, or are timers already exactly that?

Comment: one timer cleaning up once a min seems sufficient. i would not want 1000s of timers going at once, but hundreds should be ok if they don't need millisecond precision. an efficient  way would be to attach a timeout epoc date stamp upon connection, and then in your cleanup, cache Date.now() and compare to each stored expiration, and if later, remove it.

Comment: Do you realize that you can put a sessionID in a cookie and it will automatically be sent with every new socket.io connection?  The server can then examine that session and can even set expiration of the cookie to coincide with when it removes its session data.

Comment: Is there a reason that session data has to be expired every minute?  How about every 15 minutes?  That cuts your timer activity down by a factor of 15.  I would say that if you intend to support a large number of connected users, you do not want every single user causing timer activity every minute.  Your node.js server will be busy doing nothing but serving these timers which is not what you want.

Comment: Yeah I think the idea of having a timer for each session data was overkill data cleaning up. So i'll probably just go with a garbage collection loop that runs every couple of minutes or so and checks the expiration date of the session and clears it out if it has expired

Answer (score 1):

They are used frequently for timeouts, and are very efficient in cpu.

```
// ten_thousand_timeouts.js
for (var i=0;i<=10000;i++) {
  (function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i);
    },1000)
  })(i)
}
```

With 10,000 the results of logs only took .336 seconds and the act of logging it to the console took most of that time.

```
//bash script
$> time node ten_thousand_timeouts.js
1
...
9999
10000

real    0m1.336s
user    0m0.275s
sys     0m0.146s
```

I cannot imagine this being an issue for your use case.

Comment: Thats interesting, but still as pointed out by the other guys comments above its probably less "messy" to have a loop that runs every couple of minutes to clean up session data rather than attach a timer to everyone

Comment: I would actually consider the timer less "messy". For instance if every connection had a timer you could easily modify a timer for a specific connection (if you need to increase the timeout due to some activity/feedback). To do that with a loop you would need cumbersome logic. Node.js actually uses timers for this purpose with their socket timeouts https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c7be08cec18b0591381126e149cac96a05125966/lib/net.js#L299-L313